# Qt pjsip ошибка при сборке

Tags: qt, pjsip

Хочу проверить работу установленной библиотеки pjsip.
Ставил так `./configure & make dep & make install` далее скопировал простой пример с оф сайта либы:

## include

```
#include <pjsip.h>
#include <pjsua.h>
#include <pjsua2.hpp>
#include <pjlib.h>
#include <pjlib.h>
#include <pjlib-util.h>
#include <pjmedia.h>
#include <pjmedia-codec.h>
#include <pjsip.h>
#include <pjsip_simple.h>
#include <pjsip_ua.h>
#include <pjsua-lib/pjsua.h>

using namespace pj;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Endpoint *ep = new Endpoint;
    try
    {
        ep->libCreate();
    }
    catch(Error& err)
    {
        cout << "Startup error: " << err.info() << endl;
    }

    cout << "xyi";

    ep->libDestroy();
    delete ep;

    return 0;
}
```

дописал в pro файл либы:

```
INCLUDEPATH +=/home/alexey/phone/pjproject-2.5.5/pjlib/include \
              /home/alexey/phone/pjproject-2.5.5/pjlib-util/include \
              /home/alexey/phone/pjproject-2.5.5/pjnath/include \
              /home/alexey/phone/pjproject-2.5.5/pjmedia/include \
              /home/alexey/phone/pjproject-2.5.5/pjsip/include \
              /home/alexey/phone/pjproject-2.5.5/pjsip-apps/include \
              /home/alexey/phone/pjproject-2.5.5/third_party/include \

LIBS += -L/home/alexey/phone/pjproject-2.5.5/pjlib/lib \
        -L/home/alexey/phone/pjproject-2.5.5/pjlib-util/lib \
        -L/home/alexey/phone/pjproject-2.5.5/pjnath/lib \
        -L/home/alexey/phone/pjproject-2.5.5/pjmedia/lib \
        -L/home/alexey/phone/pjproject-2.5.5/pjsip/lib \
        -L/home/alexey/phone/pjproject-2.5.5/pjsip-apps/lib \
        -L/home/alexey/phone/pjproject-2.5.5/third_party/lib \
```

получаю при сборке ошибку

```
undefined reference to `pj::Endpoint::Endpoint()'
undefined reference to `pj::Endpoint::libCreate()'
undefined reference to `pj::Endpoint::libDestroy(unsigned int)'
undefined reference to `pj::Error::info[abi:cxx11](bool) const'
```

подсветка синтаксиса есть. Переопределять классы можно. Я это к тому  что qt видит их. Не пойму в чем дело? Может в настройки компилятора нужно что то указать?

Comment: Это только значит, что Qt Creator видит заголовочные файлы `.h`, как, если бы вы создали класс, в нем задекларировали функцию, но не описали ее

Comment: т.е. не видит cpp файлы?

Comment: в данном случае "бинарного аналога" cpp ). Подозреваю, хочет еще какую-нибудь библиотеку, в которой описан класс `Endpoint` (бинарный код его функций)

Comment: мне кажется еще не хватает `-l(имя_библиотеки)`, то есть если есть библиотека `libsomelib` то надо поставить `-lsomelib`. Этот процесс можно автоматизировать - правой кнопкой по проекту и `Add Library`. Подробнее: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html

Comment: g++ main.cpp -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs libpjproject` вот так из консоли заработало. Как мне теперь в про файл это добавить

Comment: вот вот так помогло. INCLUDEPATH += `pkg-config --cflags --libs libpjproject`
LIBS += `pkg-config --cflags --libs libpjproject`
PKGCONFIG += libpjproject